# Remote Python debugging with PyCharm and Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, pycharm

I'm developing an application with PyCharm and Vagrant.

How can I run and debug remote Python processes inside of my Vagrant box from PyCharm?

Comment: Have you taken a look at how it can be done from the JetBrains documentation? There's a tutorial there for setting Vagrant up with PyCharm.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Simply configure a remote interpreter for your project with Vagrant. It's actually fairly easy to do, it's just not in the docs.